# Writing a new column to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am attempting to automatically update a list of reddit subscribers to popular crypto subreddits.
I am calling a number from the PRAW API. I am successfully feeding the API with the cryptocurrency I want via a csv, and then printing it to terminal.

I am having trouble then taking that printed array and writing it to a new csv.

I am very new to python, coding, and Stack Overflow so any help or suggestions would be appreciated! I'm in version 3.7.1 and on Windows and using IDLE.

```
import csv

with open('Reddit.csv') as csvinput:
    with open('Reddit2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader= csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        rows = next(reader)
        rows.append('Test')
        all.append(rows)

        for rows in reader:
            subreddit = reddit.subreddit(rows[0])
            print(subreddit.subscribers)
            rows.append(rows[0])
            all.append(subreddit.subscribers)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Expecting to see the original list from the 'Reddit' csv in the first column, and a new column for the subscriber count in the second column.

Comment: Apparently you're not getting what you expected. What _are_ you getting instead—what's the problem? Also what is the variable `reddit`?

Comment: so the code was running fine, it would print out correctly to terminal. But there was an issue with the write function as I had it. Messa's comment below fixed it perfectly (I don't yet understand why lol, but I'll be looking into it.)

The `reddit` variable is part of the `praw package` which is part of reddit's API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be here:

```
    for rows in reader:
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit(rows[0])
        print(subreddit.subscribers)
        rows.append(rows[0])
        all.append(subreddit.subscribers)
```

Is it better when you try this?

```
    for row in reader:
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit(row[0])
        row.append(str(subreddit.subscribers))
        all.append(row)
```

Comment: That's done it! Thank you Messa! 

I was unfamiliar with the str() function but that makes sense!
If you don't mind me asking, why do I all.append the 'rows' variable and not the subreddit.subscribers? Is the script first gathering all the numbers into the "rows" and then inserting it into "all" at once?

Comment: Also, this was my first successful original script, so I'm PSYCHED. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Ratphil The rows variable actually contains just one row. That’s how for loop works - it takes items (lines from input csv in this case) one by one and for each item executes the indented block. So you get one line, append subscribers count to it (converted from number to string) and the line is added to the list “all”. In the end you output the “all”.